# Binding arbitrary function in wxwidgets

Tags: c++, c++11, wxwidgets, bind

I want to create a number of composite objects, each containing a scrolled list and some buttons (for my example, I've reduced the code to creating just one of the objects with just one button). All of these objects will be very similar, except for the layout, size, and the functions called by the buttons
(i.e. for each object, the callback for the same button can be different).

So, in the constructor for these composite objects, I want to receive the functions to bind to the buttons (again, in my example, it will be one button).

I have an example version that works (without the Bind function being passed), and an example that won't compile when I try to add the code passing in the function to Bind.

Here's the compiler error:

```
stack2.cpp: In constructor ‘MainPanel::MainPanel(wxFrame*)’:
stack2.cpp:106:94: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyAddRemoveList::MyAddRemoveList(MainPanel*, const char [12], const char [11], int, int, int, bool, void (MyAddRemoveList::*)(wxCommandEvent&))’
  106 | xLB_MULTIPLE | wxLB_HSCROLL | wxLB_NEEDED_SB, false, &MyAddRemoveList::OnAddToList);
                                                                           1,68          Top
tack2.cpp:61:1: note: candidate: ‘MyAddRemoveList::MyAddRemoveList(wxWindow*, const char*, const char*, int, int, long int, bool, func)’
   61 | MyAddRemoveList::MyAddRemoveList(wxWindow *panel, const char *display_name,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
stack2.cpp:62:79: note:   no known conversion for argument 8 from ‘void (MyAddRemoveList::*)(wxCommandEvent&)’ to ‘func’ {aka ‘void (*)(wxCommandEvent&)’}
   62 |       const char *table_name, int w, int h, long style, bool do_extract, func fpt) :
      |                                                                          ~~~~~^~~
stack2.cpp:41:7: note: candidate: ‘MyAddRemoveList::MyAddRemoveList(const MyAddRemoveList&)’
   41 | class MyAddRemoveList : public wxBoxSizer {
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
stack2.cpp:41:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 8 provided
stack2.cpp:41:7: note: candidate: ‘MyAddRemoveList::MyAddRemoveList(MyAddRemoveList&&)’
stack2.cpp:41:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 8 provided
make: *** [stack2.make:94: stack2.o] Error 1
```

I don't understand why the compiler can't cast `void (*)(wxCommandEvent&)` to `void (MyAddRemoveList::*)(wxCommandEvent&)`. This is my problem.

Notes:

- I have pruned the code down to a minimal version (one that "works" without the Bind, and one with Bind that  won't compile). But again, they're each about 100 lines and I don't know if that's too long to include in a question here.
- POP OS 22.04
- wxwidgets 3.0

How can I do this?

Here's the (hopefully) relevant code.

For clarity I have this:

```
using func = void(*)(wxCommandEvent& event);
```

Here's the constructor:

```
MyAddRemoveList::MyAddRemoveList(wxWindow *panel, const char *display_name, const char *table_name, int w, int h, long style, bool do_extract, func fpt) : wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL) {

/* stuff here */
```

Here's my attempt to bind:

```
/* stuff here */

wxButton *add = new wxButton(panel, wxID_ADD, "+", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT);

add->Bind( wxEVT_BUTTON, fpt );
```

Here's the call to the constructor:

```
lookup_lists[0] = new MyAddRemoveList(this, "Ingredients", "ingredient", 80, 200, wxLB_MULTIPLE | wxLB_HSCROLL | wxLB_NEEDED_SB, false, &MyAddRemoveList::OnAddToList);
```

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow - is there a way to upload files into a question?

Comment: @SteveQuinn, you don't have to upload the code. If you say you have a small example - edit the OP and copy/paste the code there. Im just guessing you have about 5 lines of C++ code which can be easily sent in the OP.

Comment: Pointer-to-member-function and pointer-to-function are two completely different, unrelated types. You can't pass a regular non-member function where a member function is required, or vice versa; because a member function needs an object to be called on (what becomes `this` in the function body), and non-member function does not.

Comment: I have added some hopefully relevant bits of code to the example.

Comment: Igor, thanks for the responses. How would one get an anonymous member function pointer?  Also, the function I'm attempting to pass is a member function of MyAddRemoveList.  Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it all wrong and incorrect.

Please look at the different samples on how to make the GUI using wxWidgets.

Let me try and fix that for you.

You constructor is incorrect.
Do not pass the function into the constructor. Do it like this:

```
MyAddRemoveList::MyAddRemoveList(wxWindow *panel, const char *display_name, const char *table_name, int w, int h, long style, bool do_extract) : wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL)
{

    // The button creation code seems to be fine if you actually do have a "panel" created somewhere.

    wxButton *add = new wxButton(panel, wxID_ADD, "+", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT);

    // The Bind call will look like this:

    add->Bind( wxeVT_BUTTON, &MyAddRemoveList::OnButtonClick, this );
}

MyAddRemoveList::OnButtonClick(wxCommandEvent &event)
{

    // Put generic code to start here

    switch( event.GetEventObject() )
    {
        case add:
        // Code unique to add
        break;
        case remove:
        // Code unique to remove
        break;
    }

    // Put generic code to finish the handler
}
```

And of course get rid of that func - you will not be needing it.

Finally you will be better off with using `wxPanel` instead of `wxBoxSizer` as sizers are not windows - they are just layout mechanism.

And please learn the language first - C++, Python, Perl, Ruby. All this languages have some way using wxWidgets.

Only when you know the language - go with the wxWidgets.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Igor.  I am definitely new to c++ (DB and perl web background from 10 years ago). I do actually have everything laying out nicely (fun with sizers), and there are 11 of these list/button objects on the panel (among other things).  The buttons' actions will vary among these objects, so I was hoping do it in the constructor (which seems logical to me) but I will go with your suggestion.  Thanks again!

Comment: @SteveQuinn, you can definitly create those buttons and Bind() the handlers to them, but you can't do everything there. And I sure hope you lern the language prior to jumping with the wxWidgets. Perl does have a binding, but its seriously outdated, and from what I understand is abandoned.

Comment: Thanks Igor.  I actually have the perl binding (with alienwidgets) and have written some things but, as you say, it's way out of date.  To be clear, the Db, perl and web work I did ended 10 years ago when I retired, and I didn't write a line of code after that until a couple months ago, so I'm rusty. I suppose learning c++ and wxwidgets at the same time is a bit of a fools errand. Again though, I'll use your suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: @SteveQuinn, np. Enjoy your retirement. And have fun with C++/wxWidgets.

Comment: @SteveQuinn, I edited the code so that you can better understand the structure of wxWidgets program. Please review and apply. If you have any questions - don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks again Igor.  My issue is that the add function will be different for different MyAddRemoveList objects, which is why I was trying to send it in to the constructor. I guess I can send in a type and have a switch inside the constructor.  I'll figure something out.

Comment: @SteveQuinn, don't. Code is updated.

Comment: You can `Bind()` the same function to all of your buttons and it will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks again!  The actual add function itself will differ for the different MyAddRemoveList - some make a DB hit, some display a file chooser, some pull up a url.  So it seems I need the switch in the constructor, or else I have to figure out which add button I'm dealing with in the callback.  I thought, since I know which button I'm dealing with in the constructor, that's where the bind would be, but with the bound function varying based on context (which is why I was trying send in a function pointer in the first place)..  Don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: @SteveQuinn, no it doesn't. Just make a different function for every scenario - the code will be easier to maintain and understand in time.